# Is there a way to assign a jogl shape to a variable?

Tags: java, jogl, 2d-games

I am trying to create the game pong and drew a paddle with 4 vertices in jogl. I wanted to assign that jogl shape to a variable in order to test if it intersects with the ball which is just a jogl point. It would be helpful if there was something with a .intersects method but that is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there is no way to do this effectively in jogl.... You could assign a java rectangle or a rect to it. But, both won't be nearly as effective as they are not exact. The java rectangle matches the coordinates that are used by java not jogl. So if you matched them I suppose that would work. With the jogl rect, it is not precise and hard to assign vertices to it.